# Constructing Q objects dynamically, or NOP

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to construct filter dynamically based on passed query parameters. Code below. 
Because the filter might end up empty, in which case all objects need to be returned, this is coming out very ugly.

Is there a way to do this cleanly? Maybe if there is a default Q that means 'do not nothing'?

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    q = None
    for field, value in request.GET.items():
        if field not in Project._meta.fields:
            continue
        if q is None:
            q = Q(**{'{}'.format(field): value})
        else:
            q &= Q(**{'{}'.format(field): value})

    if q is None:
        projects = get_objects_for_user(request.user, ['api.view_project', 'api.edit_project', 'api.owner_project'], any_perm=True)
    else:
        projects = get_objects_for_user(request.user, ['api.view_project', 'api.edit_project', 'api.owner_project'], any_perm=True).filter(q)

    ser = ProjectSerializer(projects, many=True)

    return Response(ser.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Have you tried `Q()`?

Comment: I am so stupid. I did, it didn't work, but that was because of another bug, and I forgot to try this again. Thanks a lot! Do you want to post this as an official answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `Q()` should filter out nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html):

Example of filter class:

```
import django_filters

class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'user',
            'user__username',
        ]
```

Example of view function:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    projects = get_objects_for_user(request.user, ['api.view_project', 'api.edit_project', 'api.owner_project'], any_perm=True)

    projects = ProjectFilter(request.GET, queryset=projects)

    ser = ProjectSerializer(projects, many=True)

    return Response(ser.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```